# GeoServer CORS Error only in Firefox and mobile Browsers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, apache, firefox

I have created an Openlayers Web Client, which is able to do GET and POST Requests to a Geoserver WFS(-T).
I enabled CORS in the Geoserver web.xml file (Geoserver is installed in Tomcat) by adding this code:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After this, everything works fine, except with the Firefox browser. Anyway, I receive a CORS error like this:

```
Cross-origin query blocked: The same-source rule prohibits reading the external resource at http://xxx:8080/geoserver/wfs. (Reason: CORS preflight response failed). Status code: 403.
```

I found this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514666/why-is-this-cors-request-failing-only-in-firefox) on Stack Overflow.

The solutions described there didn't worked for me:

- Comma delimited Access-Control-Allow-Methods (POST, GET, OPTIONS)
- Adding the `.withCredentials = true;` option in the `XMLHttpRequest()`
- Allow Firefox to trust CA's in the Windows Certificate Store by set the `security.enterprise_roots.enabled`  value to `true`

Does anybody know how to fix this error related to a Geoserver - Tomcat - Openlayers configuration ?

**Update:** In the Geoserver log, I get the following:

`org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@60c93e32`

This is an example request:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:crowdnew="http://www.crowdnew.com"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://klimnet2.geographie.ruhr-uni-bochum.de:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd
http://www.crowdnew.com http://klimnet2.geographie.ruhr-uni-bochum.de:8080/geoserver/crowdnew/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=crowdnew%3Apunkte">
<wfs:Insert>
<crowdnew:punkte>
<crowdnew:geom>
<gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#25832">
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">376920.85501376115,5701873.816694793</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Point>
</crowdnew:geom>
<crowdnew:pkuid>648.0</crowdnew:pkuid>
<crowdnew:objektart>2.0</crowdnew:objektart>
<crowdnew:melder>test</crowdnew:melder>
<crowdnew:kurzbeschr>test</crowdnew:kurzbeschr>
</crowdnew:punkte>
</wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

Comment: No idea I'm afraid - I use firefox and GeoServer daily and have never seen this issue, can you check the network logs in your browsers and compare to chrome or curl to see if you can see a difference?

Comment: In the network log it says `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI` at a POST Request

Comment: When I open the XML response of the Geoserver, I reveive this: `<ows:ExceptionText>
Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@2eb2a242
</ows:ExceptionText>`

Comment: So your request is getting through but is not correct - I doubt CORs is to blame

Comment: This is strange, in Chrome, IE and Opera, it works.

Comment: please add the URL that we can test at

Comment: The problem is, that the page is only available via VPN from my university.

Comment: Now, it is accessible without VPN, but I get the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". Does anybody know why this happens?